# Why would all versions of IE push a entire column down a page?

Tags: css

Ok sensible answers and not "IE is crap"...

I've produced this site at www.letsrentuk.com and in IE it looks like this:

[image]

Now what I've done in the CSS is change the width on the left column, however nothing changed in IE.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: no idea, show some code, my first guess (of many) would be floated elements, and 2nd guess would be box model sizing interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE is crap, and that's what you get for using tables for layout!

..just kidding. Mostly.

The problem seems to be, in `ie.css`:

```
.main-right-only {
    width: 740px;
}
```

Remove that, and it works.

All other browsers have `width: 680px` applied instead, and IE needs the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah IE is crap and tables do suck. Ended up using this Joomla template and parts of it are tables for some unknown reason. Forgot about that IE.css file :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are floating that left column and there's just not enough room for it so it gets pushed down.  If it's the left column that is floated left, try putting the entire column code AFTER the right column code.  If the right column is what is floated, try putting the right column code BEFORE the left column code.  (I know, it's technically the same either way.)

Answer (score 0):

There are articles about describing IE's method of rounding percentages compared to other browsers which is why IE may have this issue when others don't. And IE is crap, too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a width issue. In IE I can see that the left main content is wider than in other browsers. Chrome computes it at 668px, with IE at 728px. This will push the main content down because it can't fit anymore. Either fix your widths or get a better CSS Reset to standardize your element properties.